# How to draw unicode boxes in Telegram API?

Tags: python, user-interface, unicode, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to draw a tic-tac-toe box with unicode-box characters, so that my telegram bot can send it to the user. If I draw in the terminal, I get a good result, something like this:

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│· · ·│· · ·│· · ·│
│X X X│X X X│X X X│
│· · ·│· · ·│· · ·│
├─────┼─────┼─────┤
│X X X│X X X│X X X│
│X X X│X X X│X X X│
│· · ·│· · ·│· · ·│
├─────┼─────┼─────┤
│X X X│X X X│X X X│
│· · ·│· · ·│· · ·│
│O O O│O O O│O O O│
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Not bad

But when I this text as a message in telegram, I get [something like this...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEZfr.png).

It seems that the problem is in that telegram assigns different sizes to different symbols. I searched online, but couldn't find any similar problems.

How do I make my telegram bot send out Unicode symbols that take up the same amount of space?

Comment: No it doesn't, the problem is that your terminal uses a monospaced font for everything, while telegram doesn't. Just stick your text in code fences (the now-universal ``` before and after) to force it to be treated like code, using a monospace font.

Comment: If you could add some code you wrote to your question that would be better, it would help me and other users in helping you. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which library you're using, but in general there should be the possibility to format the text with the fonts made available by telegram.

To explain, I'll refer to the `python-telegram-bot` library. To send a message you use `send_message()`. Documentation [here](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.send_message).

You can pass an optional `parse_mode` parameter with value `ParseMode.HTML`. This way you can format the text with different HTML tags (`<b>`, `<i>`...).

In your case you could use `<code>` which is a monospace font. The code would be something like this:

```py
from telegram import (ParseMode)

messageText = f"<code>{yourGrid}</code>"
context.bot.send_message(chat_id=123456789, text=grid, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
```

Whatever library you're using, there is definitely a way to use the fonts that Telegram makes available in messages. The font in question on Telegram takes the name of **monospace**.